# Error after copying website to new folder

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, copying

I have a website in a local directory that runs fine under VS2015. I wanted to give out the site to someone to improve the css, but not include the code. So I thought I would copy it to a new folder and strip out the relevant code. Unfortunately, even before I remove anything, the site doesn't run properly. The css is not rendered at all, though if I go to design view in VS it's fine. I get $ is undefined, as if jquery is not loaded, but the paths still have the same relation to each other, e.g. ../scripts or ~/scripts.

What do I need to alter to get the site to run as it did from its original folder?

EDIT: Folder structure added as requested.

[image: Folder Structure]

Comment: Can you show your project folder structure?

Comment: @Rahul. Added screenshot. Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops.... this is embarrassing. I closed down VS and then restarted it and now it's fine. VS must have got confused somehow.

Apologies for wasting peoples time.

Answer (score 0):

NO it certainly not complaining about `~/Scripts` folder. Not sure hat exactly you are trying to do but open up your `UI Export` projects `*.csproj` file (project file) and see if all the referencing paths still referencing to same location else change accordingly.

Comment: I don't have a csproj file, I think it's because it's a website. I have a sln and a suo file, nothing in these seems to point to an odd reference.